# Out of index error with worksheets collection and combobox on VBA from excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an exception when trying to access the worksheets collection. 
My program already populates a Combobox with the sheet names of the workbook, but when I try to access the collection It gives me an Error 9 (Out of index)
The code is the next one:

```
With Me.cmbHojas
Set regis.Hoja = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(.List(.ListIndex))
End With
```

cmbHojas is the combobox's name and it's fully populated by the initialize event from the form... It has all the sheet names, and I don't know what's the reason for this error to happen... 
regis.Hoja is a property (Worksheet Type) of one of my objects
The error comes from the right side of the assignment 
Thank you very much

EDIT: I'll post the entire code that give problems

```
Private Sub btnTabla_Click() 
Dim i As Long
Dim c1 As Integer
Dim fila As Variant
Dim f As Long, c As Long
Dim leer As String
Dim celda As Range
Dim regis As New Registro
Dim work As Worksheet
With Me.cmbHojas
Set regis.Hoja = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(.List(.ListIndex))
End With
origen:
On Error Resume Next
Set celda = Application.InputBox("Seleccione la celda de origen", _
"Entrada", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If celda Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "No seleccionó celda", vbCritical, "Entrada requerida"
GoTo origen
End If 
Set regis.CeldaInicial = celda

'Primera celda de escritura de la consulta

destino:
On Error Resume Next
Set celda = Application.InputBox("Seleccione la celda de insercion", _
"Entrada", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If celda Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "No seleccionó celda", vbCritical, "Entrada requerida"
GoTo destino
End If

' Iterador hasta que se termina la hoja

f = celda.Row: c = celda.Column

Do While True
regis.linea

fila = regis.regis
i = regis.FilaComparacion

For c1 = 0 To UBound(fila)
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(f, c + c1).Value = fila(c1)
Debug.Print fila(c1) + " " + Str(i)
Next c1
f = f + 1 
If (regis.Terminado) Then
MsgBox ("Se han terminado de leer los datos")
Exit Do
End If

Loop

End Sub
```

I'm spanish-speaking so it's in spanish...
The aim of that program is to make a query in a long excel sheet... The class "Registro" is working... I've tested it several times with my program.... That's not the problem...
The problem is in the code above

Comment: How do we reproduce this error?

Comment: I can't understand.... What's your question and thanks for answering

Comment: It is almost impossible to help you without more details about your problem. Put yourself in my position: what would you want to know?

Comment: If I call the worksheets by their names it gives errors of indexes... The question is: How can I make that "Set" line without giving error....
It works sometimes